# Real-time gps tracking in mobile phones with Python

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, kivy

sorry I am at the noob level in doing this: real-time gps tracking in mobile phones. I have done deep searching already about this, but everything is new to me and I don't know where and how to start.

This is for our school project. What we wanted to do is develop a mobile application using python, kivy, and google map api that is capable of tracking other mobile phones which are also using the mobile application that we're going to create. In general, there are several mobile phones in the area (1km radius) using our application and they are tracking each other. (This is just part of our school project: tracking part).

I have watched videos, read forums, etc. But, I'm not getting anything because everything is new to me. My concerns are (note: I have created a mobile app before):

1. Where and how do I start?
2. Are there any python modules to use? What are those?
3. What are the steps? (Sorry... I don't know if this is the right question to ask).

Please. I know I'm noob. Your help is much appreciated and you'll be our hero that saves us from failing our subject. :D

Comment: May I just ask what school are you in and what year? I am really curious because I want to know at what level of education they require such "advanced" stuff from you... Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: I am a graduate student in second year, but I am in a class mixed with undergrad students. It's a university from Philippines.

Comment: Well, what do you think are the component parts? Can you work out the GPS location of a single phone? Before you do anything, make sure you understand the smaller pieces that have to come together - you don't need programming knowledge to get the plan together. This question is too broad to answer properly.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. The undergrad programming here in Slovenia is complete shit (not all subject, excluding Programming 2, Compilers, and some others) because the student lobby is so strong and creates such an oppression that the uni lowers standards from year to year. **They even moved Architecture of computer systems which is essential computer course from year 2 to year 1 and halved the stuff they teach!!!** I know this is off-topic, but still.

Comment: @roganjosh: so that means if I can make it work on a single phone, I can just pass the current location of that phone to other phones, and let the other phones mark that single phone's location on the map. Thanks!

Comment: @RF_956 exactly... You must just find the way on how the device will communicate between each other.

Comment: @campovski your answer strikes a good balance. As for your question RF_956, I'm suggesting you stand by a whiteboard with your group mates and try and work out how all the mini-tasks link together. You never start with a giant body of work and aim to do that in one go; everything is composed of smaller parts and you already have a good answer

Comment: @campovski From my own experience, most of the developers/programmers I know actually learn from self-taught approach. In  this subject that we are having a project, we are just taught with principles and theories, and our project is the implementation of those principles. So, basically, this is a self-taught approach. However, we are still consulting our professors for guidance.

Comment: @roganjosh great comment! Indeed, programming is gathering small pieces (like basic functions) into parts (like classes) that are then collected to form the whole (a project).

Comment: @RF_956 yeah, but you are a postgrad student, not undergrad ;). Postgrads are meant to do more research-oriented stuff. I will actually open a question regarding teaching standards across the world (not on SO, maybe in meta).

Comment: @campovski yeah, but even in post-graduate level, you still need to do some development/programming. You can find better results in research if you use technology, and by using technology it means you have to know how to program and develop, and how to use that technology. And there are some technologies which are not taught in school, so you have to learn it yourself.

Comment: Hi! I am searching for exactly the same data for a project in university. Do you have any direction that you could provide?

Answer (score 4):

1. You start by searching the web, Google, YouTube,... which you say you have already done. Proceed to answer 2 or read more. I have found some interesting links for you:

   - [Learn How to Send Requests to the Google Maps API With Python](http://www.instructables.com/id/Real-Time-GPS-Tracker-with-Integrated-Google-Maps/)
   - [GooMPy: Interactive Google Maps for Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzuiEnbVU2U)
   - [How to get current location with Google Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation)
2. Yes, there is a [Python module for Google Maps](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). Also as mentioned in second bullet of point 1, there is some simple project called [GooMPy](https://github.com/simondlevy/GooMPy) which apperently provides gui for Google Maps api, although I haven't researched it much.
3. Knowing above stuff I would be pretty comfortable in started coding myself. But first you need to ask yourself: *"Do I know how to do the next things?"*:

   - Find out how to get GPS location of a phone (look at one of the links above).
   - Decide where the data received from phones will be stored (you will need a server that will communicate with phones, receive their current GPS location, send location of other users to specific user, etc.).
   - Do I know how to implement server-side and client-side stuff? That being do I know how to set up a server? Do I know how a phone can communicate with server? You want to use a server as mediator for 2 reasons:

     1. Communication with server is easier to implement then P2P (peer-to-peer which in your case would be phone to phone).
     2. **Main reason** is that if you use server as mediator, you leave a lot of work that needs to be done to server, thus resulting in lower battery usage on phone and less internet traffic on phone (the latter might not be the problem if you have unlimited data transfer, but will still result in slower loading time). The work that needs to be done is: collect data about other active users, send data to active users, retrieve data from active users. If you implement the P2P way, what a phone would need to do is first gather data from **all** other active phones that are online, where they are, and then send its location to **all** other phones. If you implement the server way, instead of things mentioned, the phone only needs to send its location to **one** device (server) and receive data about other users from **one** device (again server). By doing less operations on phone, you save **a lot** of battery.

   Once you know how to do the above stuff (and it might be more), you can ask yourself *"What do I need to do?* / *What steps do I need to take in order to complete my project?*. You will need to implement next things:

   - main GUI of your application;
   - logging in and signing up;
   - reading current GPS location;
   - sending GPS location to server;
   - receiving GPS locations of other users from server;
   - embedding Google Maps api and GUI in your app (maybe GooMPy is already a solution, I don't know).

Hope you find this helpful. I cannot be too explanatory because you need to do your project on your own. If you have any additional questions, comment below and I will edit.
   - sending curre

Comment: Hi thank you. The links you give will be useful. One thing I want to clarify. What do you mean by "server"? Is it some other device that serves as mediator between mobile phones?

What we wanted do is these mobile phones are directly communicating with each other. But, still I am curious about the server thing.

Comment: Yes, indeed. A server can be a bad PC that will serve as mediator. Why you want a server and not P2P (peer-to-peer or mobile to mobile device in your case) is because communication with server is easier to implement, but the more important thing is... I will edited in the answer to complete it.

Comment: Is it possible to have a cloud server? Which would you recommend? :)

Comment: Here I cannot help you (I have never done anything with cload services). All I know is that yes, you certainly can and that it might be harder to implement

Comment: you could use heroku or aws or a number of other providers with a free tiers for your cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

@campovski's answer is good in general, but since you use kivy, and android, you'll certainly want to check the following things:

`Plyer`[1] for getting gps locations from python on mobile devices, it'll make it easy for the app to get the gps data of it's own device.

Now, you want to sync with other users of the app, so you need some way of communicating, the easier is to configure the app to talk to a server and send updates about its position, and get the positions of others in return, you can do that with a simple rest server using `bottle`[2] or `flask`[3], or any server side technology, but obviously python is better :) (and i'm totally unbiased ;)).

Then you'll want to display your friends on the map, for this, since you use kivy, you'll certainly want to have a look at garden.mapview[4] which will give you a widget to display a map with markers that you can keep up to date when you get new data.

You still have some work to do, for communication with server, setting up shared session with the group, scheduling updates and stuff, but with all that most of the work is already done, you only have to connect the dots, good luck.

[1] plyer: https://github.com/kivy/plyer

[2] bottle: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

[3] flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

[4] garden.mapview https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview

Comment: Oh.. I see! .... Thank you so much. :) In number 3, I think I will use django since I am working with django projects too.